# MySQL Database Structure with revisions/history

Tags: mysql, database, design-patterns, version-control

I've been looking into various DB Structures for the task I'm trying to achieve but it seems like my ideas are flawed. I first looked into wiki's DB but seemed a bit complicated for what I want to do and then I saw this which looks closer to what I am trying to do.

I was thinking of having a table which will keep the final form and an extra table where it will keep all the revisions/history. I am not sure though if that would be too much. Although I am not sure the above example is using this method.

Comment: Table that keeps the final form should just keep the revision number and identifier. The table with revisions should keep all the content and revision number. You're on the right track, you just don't have to keep the final form materialized, just its revision and identifier. Do a simple join and you can easily get current valid content. If something goes wrong, change the revision number in "final form" table. Ez pz.

Answer (score -1):

I've done something similar - a database table with the ability to fork into multiple revisions and unlimited undo capability, without slowing down the database. I used an additional table to keep track of the "change vectors". Each change can be undone.

There are several types of transactions, so your change table has to keep track. For example, the simple one would be value change. You record what the position (unique ID and column name) is, and the value before and after the change. During undo, the previous value is restored.

The most expensive change is the addition or removal of a column. This is where you utilize an external storage if you don't want to have an excessive longtext/longblob column. A nosql database such as mongodb is suitable for this use.

Hope this helps get you started.